# How does HDBSCAN generate cluster hierarchy?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, clustering, data-science-model, dbscan

HDBSCAN generates the minimum spanning tree where each vertex represents the data point whereas the edges represent the mutual reachability distance.
But how does it generate the cluster hierarchy?

I don't understand the method for obtaining cluster hierarchy from MST.
But the straightforward and intuitive idea that comes to my mind is,
We set 'ε' to the max value and then iteratively decrease it and remove all the edges with a distance more than 'ε'. Why HDBSCAN follows a different approach please help me understand the intuition behind mutual reachability distance.

Comment: For reference, HDBSCAN has a nice docs page detailing how it works: https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/how_hdbscan_works.html